# Swift operator `subscript` []

Tags: swift, operator-overloading, subscript-operator

I am beginner with the `Swift` having no advance knowledge with operators.

I have the following class

```
class Container {
   var list: [Any] = [];
}
```

I want to implement the operator `subscript []` in order to access the data from `list`.

I need something like this:

```
var data: Container = Container()
var value = data[5]
// also    
data[5] = 5
```

Also I want to be able to write something like this:

```
data[1][2]
```

Is it possible considering that element `1` from `Container` is an `array`?

Thanx for help.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It looks like there are 2 questions here.

### 1. How can I enable `subscripting` on my own custom class?

To enable `subscripting` on your class `Container` you need to implement the `subscript` computed property like this.

```
class Container {
    private var list : [Any] = [] // I made this private

    subscript(index:Int) -> Any {
        get {
            return list[index]
        }
        set(newElm) {
            list.insert(newElm, atIndex: index)
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use it this way.

```
var container = Container()
container[0] = "Star Trek"
container[1] = "Star Trek TNG"
container[2] = "Star Trek DS9"
container[3] = "Star Trek VOY"

container[1] // "Star Trek TNG"
```

### 2. Can I access one element of `Container` that supports subscripting writing something like `data[1][2]`?

If we use your example no, you cannot. Because `data[1]` returns something of type `Any`. And you cannot subscript `Any`.

But if you add a cast it becomes possible

```
var container = Container()
container[0] = ["Enterprise", "Defiant", "Voyager"]
(container[0] as! [String])[2] // > "Voyager"
```

Answer (score 6):

A workaround is to leverage multiple parameters in `subscript`

So instead of `data[1][2]`, you can say `data[1, 2]`. This will be handy in some cases

```
struct Container {
  subscript(a: Int, b: Int) -> String {
    print(a)
    print(b)
    return "possible"
  }
}

let data = Container()
data[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

### Swift 5.2: Subscripting in UserDefaults values - Useful Manager

> Static function with generic type

```
class Defaults {

   static subscript<T>(key: DefaultsKey) -> T? {
      get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: key.rawValue) as? T
      }
      set {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key.rawValue)
      }
    }
}

enum DefaultsKey: String {
    case firstKey = "JSGHDjasgchvsas"
}
```

**Save value**

```
Defaults[.firstKey] = 34
```

**Get value**

```
let value: Int = Defaults[.firstKey]
```

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

```
class Container
{
    var list: [AnyObject] = ["hello" , "world"];
    subscript ( i : Int) -> AnyObject{
        get{
            return list[i]
        }
        set{
            list[i] = newValue
        }
    }
}

var c : Container = Container()
println(c[1])

c[1] = "lol"

println(c[1])
```

For more information about operator : http://nshipster.com/swift-operators/

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for subscripts. You can make subscripts for your own type like the following example:

```
class Container {
    var list = [["Hello", "World"], ["Foo", "Bar"]]

    subscript(index: Int) -> [String] {
        get {
            return list[index]
        }
        set {
            list.insert(newValue, atIndex: index)
        }
    }
}
```

The above example works with the double `[ ]` only because I know that we are going to return an `Array`. Here the `Array` contain Strings as an example, but you could of course swap in your own type

```
var container = Container()

container[0][0] = "Stack"
container[0][1] = "Overflow"

print(container[0][0]) // "Stack"
print(container[1][1]) // "Bar"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class Container {
    private var list = [Any]()
    subscript(_ index: Int) -> Int? {
       get {
            guard index < list.count else { return nil }
            return list[index]
      }
       set(newValue){
          guard let unwrappedElement = newValue else { return }
          list.insert(unwrappedElement, at: index)
       }
    }
}
```

> Here we are using subscripts with optional type to handle index out of range.

Comment: I know this is an old post (also neat solution), but shouldn't this technically cause a crash? returning nil can have unforeseen consequences and also isn't in line with the way subscripting works. at the very least it should raise an out of bounds exception or something?

Comment: You quoted 
"but shouldn't this technically cause a crash? " 
Signature ``` subscript(_ index: Int) -> Int?```  says that,  it will guarantee a return value, Return value can be desired request accessed or nil in case of absence

Comment: Handling crash will definitely you want in your code.